# Ошибка 419 при регистрации

Tags: php, curl, https, csrf

пытаюсь зарегистрироваться на сайте с помощью CURL, задача то в общем, не сложная, но столкнулся с одной проблемой, а именно несовпадение  **CSRF** токена.

Тут же назревают вопрос, **где его искать**?

Как вариант, на предыдущей странице, где заполняется форма для регистрации. Сначала хотел сделать так, но потом возник вопрос, по идее он должен быть в самой форме, но его там нет, нашёл его в `meta` теге, но вроде его место совсем не там.

Тогда же возникает второй вопрос, **куда его передавать**?

Если мы токен изначально брали не из формы, то нужно ли передавать его POST`oм или в заголовке?

Как видите, совсем запутался, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Ниже код:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170");   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170",
        "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
        "Referer: http://www.test.ru"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test.com/auth/register'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://test.com/'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query(['email' => 'fnuwssfowjwhggy@mail.ru', 'password' => 'aMelWF$95F', 'password_confirmation' => 'aMelWF$95F', 'acceptWarning' => 1, 'referer' => 'https://test.com/', 'terms' => 1, 'captcha' => 1]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

Вот ответ сервера:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 11:10:13
GMT Content-Type: application/json 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Connection: keep-alive 
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d0b107c3a7ee5cb8be22cf3db8a7456671587640213; 
expires=Sat, 23-May-20 11:10:13 GMT; path=/; 
domain=.test.com; 
HttpOnly; 
SameSite=Lax; 
Secure Cache-Control: no-cache, private 
h3-23=":443"; 
ma=86400 
cf-request-id: 024854362b00004d9071126200000001 
{"response":null,"status":419,"errors":{"message":["CSRF token mismatch."]},"notification":null,"warning":null,"_token":"VBpYX4A22eKIq20QgaGJ1mOBeyCiTKxlsw5Nbj8b"}
```

Comment: Ищите лучше. Смотрите в инструментах разработчика в браузере какие запросы и с какими данными уходят на сервер

Comment: в заголовках токен передавать надо, не уверен но скорее всего заголовок будет такой: "X-CSRF-Token: и токен из meta

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка 419 обозначает что форма не найдена

Comment: В последней строчку написано же: `"status":419,"errors":{"message":["CSRF token mismatch."]}`